# React transition inline style won't apply

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions, react-transition-group

I am working with custom **Transition** component and my inline styling just wont apply. I tried everything what is in my power and just got myself angry. Can somebody explain why this doesn't work.
Modal show itself on initial load and by clicking on button for show or not show this doesn't react. I mean state updates correctly (this console.log shows 0 and 1 when it should) but styling just wont apply.

```
import classes from "./App.module.css";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";
import Modal from "./components/Modal/Modal";
import List from "./components/List/List";
import Backdrop from "./components/Backdrop/Backdrop";
import { useState } from "react";
import Transition from "react-transition-group/cjs/Transition";


function App() {
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);

  const onOpenModalHandler = () => {
    setModalOpen(true);
  };

  const onCloseModalHandler = () => {
    setModalOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes["App"]}>
      <h1>React Animations</h1>
      <Transition in={modalOpen} timeout={1000} onMountEnter onMountExit>
        {(state) => {
          console.log(state);
          console.log(state === "exiting" || state === "exited" ? 0 : 1);
          return ReactDOM.createPortal(
            <Modal
              closeModal={onCloseModalHandler}
              modalState={modalOpen}
              style={{
                transition: `opacity 300ms ease-out`,
                opacity: state === "exiting" || state === "exited" ? 0 : 1,
              }}
            />,
            document.getElementById("modal")
          );
        }}
      </Transition>
      {modalOpen &&
        ReactDOM.createPortal(
          <Backdrop />,
          document.getElementById("backdrop")
        )}
      <button className={"Button"} onClick={onOpenModalHandler}>
        Open Modal
      </button>
      <h3>Animating Lists</h3>
      <List />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Modal

```
import classes from "./Modal.module.css";

const Modal = (props) => {
  const classNames = props.modalState
    ? `${classes["modal-open"]} ${classes["Modal"]}`
    : `${classes["modal-close"]} ${classes["Modal"]}`;

  const onCloseModalHandler = () => {
    props.closeModal();
  };

  return (
    <div className={classNames}>
      <h1>A Modal</h1>
      <button className="Button" onClick={onCloseModalHandler}>
        Dismiss
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

Comment: What are the styles being applied for modal-open and modal-close? if you are using display: none it will never have any animated effect. Then secondly were you having issues with toggling the state to show and hide the modal?

Comment: There is not display none and without <Transition/> (modalOpen && <Modal/>) works as it should.

Comment: Can you add the code for the Transition component?

Comment: Transition component is actually third part library. I've fixed this error right now. If you want to check I can push it to github and send it to you. Thank you for your will to help.

Comment: Happy you were able to get it to work, happy coding.